# Which short-circuit-current can be expected from a power supply that produces Uout=5V and Uout=4.5V?

Tags: power-supply

A power supply produces these voltages:

```
Measurement 1: Uout=5V and Rload=infinity
Measurement 2: Uout=4.5V and Rload= 1kohm
```

Which short-circuit-current can be expected?

Which voltage will be measured when a load of

> Rload=2Kohm

is connected?

Note: This is an assignment.

Comment: Seriously??? What changed between the first two measurements?

Comment: @DaveTweed I have edited the question, you can see now. I forgot to put the Rload in the measurement 1 and 2

Comment: Looks to me like your source has an output resistance that is impacting the voltage your load *sees*. Assume no current for the first measurement and then use the second measurement and associated current to determine the value.

Comment: Is this an assignment or a real-world question or ??? Assignments can be helped with so YOU can learn to answer them - but people must say that this is what they are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a student exercise, not a real-life problem, so here are some hints.

1. Let's assume the power supply can be represented as a constant voltage source, in series with a fixed output resistance. This means the output voltage drops linearly according to the output current being drawn.
2. With 'Rload=infinity', there's *no* output current being drawn, and the output voltage is 5.0V.
3. With 'Rload = 1kohm', how much output current is being drawn? (hint: 4.5Volts across a 1 kohm load resistor)
4. The output voltage has dropped by 5.0-4.5 = 0.5V when the output current is the value in (3). What is the output resistance of the power supply? (hint: 0.5V, output current from (3)).
5. What is would be the current flowing through the output resistance you just calculated, when 5.0V is applied to it? (This is the case when the output is shorted).
6. What is the current flowing through the combination of (output resistance) + 2Kohm load resistance, when 5.0V is applied to them?

Comment: Instead of step 6 can I ask. What is the voltage when current from (5) is flowing through the combination of (output resistance) + 2Kohm load resistance? to answer my last question above.